Layout Cascading Parameter is null inside pages - Blazor Server
I am trying to pass the layout as a cascaded parameter to the page that uses the layout. The issue I am facing is that the layout cascaded parameter in the page is always null.
Here is the code I am using for MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @Body
    Your Text is: @this.SomeText
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}

And this is the code I am using for Home.razor:
@page "/"
@layout MainLayout
@rendermode InteractiveServer

@using TestLayout.Components.Layout

<button @onclick="this.ClickMe">click me</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout layout { get; set; }

    public void ClickMe(EventArgs e)
    {
            this.layout.SomeText = "Some Text";
    }
}

The following line inside Home.razor is always giving me null reference exception on layout member:
this.layout.SomeText = "Some Text";
I checked some posts that claim they faced similar issues, but they didn't work with me.
In addition, I've tried passing other variables as cascaded parameters instead of passing the whole layout but also received the same result.

You can use below code to fix the issue, it works in my side.
MainLayout.razor
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @Body
    <p>Your Text is: @SomeText</p>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public string SomeText { get; set; } = "Initial Text";

    public void UpdateText(string newText)
    {
        SomeText = newText;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Index.razor
@page "/"
@layout MainLayout
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<button @onclick="ClickMe">Click me</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (Layout != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CascadingParameter received: {Layout.SomeText}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CascadingParameter is null");
        }
    }

    private void ClickMe()
    {
        if (Layout != null)
        {
            Layout.UpdateText("Some Text");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Layout is null in ClickMe");
        }
    }
}


I receive a value in "Layout" parameter inside OnParametersSet, but when it comes to ClickMe, the value returns back to null.

@AhmedH.Sharafeldin Could you share more deatils ? If you could provide some pictures, I will understand your requirement clearly.

You basic problem is you are expecting a parent component to magically render when you change it's internal state.  There's no such automatic mechanism.
You can implement changer methods in the cascaded component that trigger manual renders [as shown in the other answer], but a far better solution is to refactor the data you want to pass into data objects and then either cascade the data objects or register them as scoped services.
The following articles provide details on how to implement what has been coined the Notification Pattern

Best Way to Trigger Re-Rendering in Blazor Following Data Changes

In my Blazor server app, I want to show messages of razor.cs pages in the header. But I cannot pass the messages from the razor pages to the header


